# Select depend on other select in one Query DB

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid 4.3 I need to populate one select with the option of the other select.

I have One .jsp consulta.jsp in this file I do the first database query and this is OK. I can populate this select in jqGrid. but I have problems when I try to populate the second select or select that depend on the select of Estado. I have tried a lot of ways but I don't know which is the problem.

```
        var estados = httpGet('url/consulta.jsp');
        var estados_limpio = estados.trim();
        estados_limpio = estados_limpio.substring(0,estados_limpio.length-1);

              { name: 'Estado',
                  index: 'Estado',
                  width: anchoP(ancho, 10),
                  align: 'left',
                  editable:true,
                  edittype:"select",
                  editoptions:
                  {value:estados_limpio}, //THIS DATA LOADS OK. 
                  dataEvents: [
                      {
                        type: 'change',
                        fn: function(e){
                            var thisval = $(e.target).val();
//IN THE BELOW LINE I HAVE PROBLEMS I TRY TO LOAD THE DATA IN DIFERENT WAYS BUT IT WAS IMPOSIBLE 
                            $.get('http://URL/consulta_motivo2.jsp?id_motivo='+thisval, function(data) {
                                var res = $(data).html();
                                $("#"+rowid+"_Motivo").html(res);
                            });
                        }
                      }
                  ]
                },
                { name: 'id_motivo_consulta',
                  index: 'id_motivo_consulta',
                  hidden: true 
                },
                { name: 'Motivo',
                  index: 'Motivo',
                  width: anchoP(ancho, 20),
                  align: 'left',
                  editable: true,
                  edittype: 'select',
                  editoptions: {value:motivos}

                }
```

When I execute the file consulta.jsp It return me this:
A:Asignada;C:Confirmada;L:Cancelada;N:No asistio;R:Reprograma;
and this is Ok.

When I execute the file consulta_motivo2.jsp It return me this:

```
<SELECT>
  <OPTION>data</OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

The jsp Query is OK. The problem is in load Motivo data

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is maybe that your response from consulta_motivo2.jsp contain select tag. In order to put the html content in already created select you will need to have only option tag and data.

Look at this [Guriddo jqGrid example](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/edit_add_delete/inline_depend_dropdown/) which do exactly what you try to do